# Panda - iterating over rows for pattern recognition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to apply pattern recognition across a panda table and set their code to valid if the author name matches a certain pattern. However, I only get the incorrect values. I am iterating over each line, but I would like to apply the lambda function only if the corresponding cell's value is to 0.

```
Author     valid
Andi       0
Tomasius   0
Anke       0
```

Here is my codes:

```
df["valid"] =0
def author_check(x, y):     
    if str(x) == y:            
        return 1       
    else: 
        return 0 
import re
author_list =["Andi","Tomasius"]#]
regex_list = [".*nd*"]
for i in range(len(author_list)):
    for x in range(len(regex_list)):
        r = re.compile(regex_list[x])
        newlist = filter(r.match, author_list)
        x = len(list(newlist))        
        if x>0:                 
            df['brand'] = df.apply(lambda row: author_check(row['Author'], author_list[i]), axis=1 )
```

Once I am running this then I get

```
Author     valid
Andi       0
Tomasius   1
Anke       0
```

But I would like to have

```
Author     valid
Andi       1
Tomasius   0
Anke       0
```

What do I make wrong? Any hint would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.  First, your regex as it stands will match both `Andi` and `Anke`, because `.*nd*` is essentially saying "match 0 or more non-line-break characters, an `n` character, and 0 or more `d` characters".  Second, using a loop doesn't take advantage of Panda's capabilities.  Instead, I'd suggest using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to perform your function in a faster and more concise fashion.

Using the sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Author': ['Andi', 'Tomasius', 'Anke'], 'valid': [0, 0, 0]})
```

The following code will give you what you want:

```
df['valid'] = np.where(df.Author.str.contains('nd'), 1, 0)
```

If your query is more complicated and you need a regular expression (as per your comment), you can use that too:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:as)|(?:nd)')
df['valid'] = np.where(df.Author.str.contains(p), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do this if I would search for 'nd' and 'as', i.e. search for two strings? <br/> df['valid'] = np.where(df.Author.str.contains('nd','as'), 1, 0) does not work ..

Comment: Updated answer for regexes.